# Can't find atag link with document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector, atag

I am trying to find a link that contains: `ng-click="showModal()"` and has the innerText: 1122334455

I have tried to use the below code but it doesn't find the link(`atag`). I am not sure what could be the problem in the codeline that uses: `document.querySelector`? (That line is the problem)

**HTML code for where the atag is located and look like:**

```
<td class="col-reservation-id text-center">
  <span class="overflow-text">
    <a class="highlight" ng-click="showModal()">1122334455</a>
  </span>
</td>
```

**C#/javascript code to find the above atag**

```
public async Task<bool> clicklink(ChromiumWebBrowser browser)
{
    String atag = "document.querySelector('" + "a[ng-click=" + '"' + "showModal()" + '"' + "].innerText === '1122334455'" + "')";

    String clickinputscript = atag + ".focus(); " +
                              atag + ".click(); ";

    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        success = (await browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(clickinputscript)).Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { success = false; }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: @charlietfl I think I use the quotes correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place JS code inside `document.querySelector`'s query string.

You have to do it after selection. To do it, use `document.querySelectorAll` and a `for` loop instead:

```
for(const element of document.querySelectorAll('a[ng-click="showModal()"]').values()){
  if(element.innerText === '1122334455'){
    element.focus()
    element.click()
    break
  }
};
```

Or, converted to C#-land:

```
String clickinputscript = "for(const element of document.querySelectorAll('a[ng-click=" + '"showModal()"'+"]').values()){if(element.innerText === '1122334455'){element.focus();element.click();break;};};";
```

Comment: That is beautiful. I understand now what you mean. This did work out perfectly!. Thank you very much for your help FZs!

Answer (score -1):

It's probablly because ng-click is not propper html attribute, try to find it by id or class :)

Comment: I know it is possible to use ng-click attribute to find the tag but some other thing is wrong in my code :)